# Mapping of Complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $w = f(w)=(3+4i)z- 2 +i$  Find the images of the disk $|z-1|<1$ and the half-plane $Im(z)>1$

For the first mapping of the disk I attempted the following :

$$z = \frac{w+2-i}{3+4i}$$ which then gives us

$$|\frac{w+2-i}{3+4i} - 1| < 1$$

$$|w-(1+5i)| < |3+4i|$$

$$|w-(1+5i)| < 5$$ And this is just a circle with origin (1,5) with a radius of 5

For the second image I did the following :

Let $z=x+iy$ thus $$w =(3+4i)(x+iy)-2+i=(3x-4y-2)+i(3y+4x+1)$$

Then $y=1$ gives $u=3x-2$ and $v=4+4x$ which leads to the line $u=\frac{3}{4}v-5$

Are these mappings correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these are both examples of [Mobius Transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), the images of generalized circles (aka circles and lines) are generalized circles, which confirms already your answers are not unexpected.

Stronger, your function is of the form $az+b$ for complex $a$ and $b.$ This is merely a superposition of two actions:

1. $az$ which scales and rotates the value $z$ by a fixed amount
2. $z+b,$ which shifts the parameter $z$ in the plane.

Geometrically, we cannot convert circles to lines or lines to circles via such actions, so circles must map to circles and lines must map to lines.

---

For the first case, we have a circle: to find the circle which is its image, we first find the center of the image:
$$f(1) = 1+5i$$ 
and then figure out where a point on the edge is mapped to:
 $$f(0) = -2+i$$
Since we have $$\sqrt{(-2 - 1)^2 + (1 - 5)^2} = 5$$ we conclude we get a circle centered at $1 + 5i$ of radius $5$, which we might write as
$$\bbox[6px,border:2px solid]{|w-(1+5i)| < 5}$$

---

For the second case, note the geometry forces the image of a half plane to remain a half plane, with the boundary of our image being the image of our initial boundary. With this in mind, let us consider the images under $f$ of two points on our initial boundary, the line $\operatorname{Im}(z) = 1:$
$$f(i) = -6 + 4i$$ $$f(i+1) = -3 + 8i$$ As mentioned prior, the image must be the line through these two points, which in the coordinates on $\mathbb{R^2}$ is simply $$y = \tfrac{4}{3}x + 12$$ We must now determine which side of this line our half plane maps onto. To this end, note
$$f(2i) = -10 + 7i$$
which lies above our line. Thus our image is the set
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid]{\operatorname{Im}(z) > \tfrac{4}{3}\operatorname{Re}(z) + 12}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is there every a situation where the mapping doesn't become an image like the original ? For example , a line doesn't remain a line under a certain function.

Comment: @Kenneth most functions don't preserve shapes of geometries... It just so happens that mobius Transforms are a ass of functions that do. Your calculation techniques  are potentially more genalizable because of this, but often in applications we can decompose a function into simpler ones which change the geometry in ways we understand, in which case techniques like those in my post apply.